# Connecting Allen Bradely PLC with Node-Red

Tags: node-red, plc, node-redis

I am new to PLC & NodeRed world. I understand basics of communication with PLC.

I am studying Internet to connect & Acquire Data from AB Micrologix 1200 PLC.

Micrologix 1200 Uses DF1 Protocol Over RS232(Serial Port).

There are Lot of Softwares/Tools available such as KepwareEx Server, Nodered etc, I prefered Nodred.

I wired the micrologix1200 and Installed serial Port in Nodered.  The serial Port Node in NodRed shows connected. But I dont know How to go ahead with it and Read Tags from the PLC.

I also Came across OPC-UA server. My questions are:

1. Is my above understanding correct? Am I on right Track?
2. How should I go ahead after The serial Node in NodeRed is showing Connected(green)
3. How should I register the Tags?
4. Is there any OPC server to be installed as software between PLC and Nodered?

I searched Internet but cannot find specific example for RS232 and NodeRed AB micrologix 12.

Please Guide.

Comment: Have you tried searching for DF1 on https://flows.nodered.org?

Comment: I don't want to confuse you further, but have you considered using MQTT ?

Answer (score 1):

OPC-UA is definitely the future-proof way to connect to a PLC. This standard is now supported by most PLCs and you can use the NodeRED code to connect to any other PLC in the future.